# How can I find CSS files using golang Gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using Go with Gorilla Mux.

This is my webserver.go file

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func HomeHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  http.ServeFile(rw, r, "index.html")
}

func main() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)

  http.Handle("/", r)

  log.Println("Server running on :8080")
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
  if err != nil {
     log.Printf("Error: %s\n", err.Error())
  }
}
```

In the same folder where the webserver.go file is located is the index.html file.

/  - here is the index.html

/css - All the CSS files

/images - All the images, resource files

I manage to load the index.html file using the above code but it doesn't seem to load the CSS files and images.

inside the index.html file I have.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />
```

So it should find the css files or do I have to make sure that "Go" can find the css and image folder?
How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [http.FileServer](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) for serving all the static files independently of `gorilla/mux`.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func HomeHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(rw, r, "index.html")
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    cssHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css/"))
    imagesHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./images/"))

    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", cssHandler))
    http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", imagesHandler))
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    http.Handle("/", r)

    log.Println("Server running on :8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: How would I add this to my above code to make it work with my structure exactly ?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. Unfortunately I couldn't get that working either. Using your above code as it is. Is it possible to somehow debug to see why my CSS files are not loaded ?

Comment: I got it working with your above code example. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: I have a question regarding your code. If I want to place my index.html file, css and images folder inside a subfolder, lets call it MyLoginPage. Where in the code should I add that subfolder so my Go program can find the files ?

Comment: explanation of this code would be great