# why i can't connect css file using gorilla/mux.Router net/http.Handle

Tags: html, css, go

I looked at all similar questions and connected the file as it was said there, but despite this, the file does not work.
I don't know what to do, what did I do wrong

main.go

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))
    r.HandleFunc("/index", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/html/test.html")
}
```

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Znh.png)

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/test.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
        asdfasd
    </body>
</html>
```

test.css

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

Comment: What does "the file does not work" mean precisely? I mean, you launch your web browser, open up its DevTools window (F12 in all of them), switch to its "network" tab, then navigate the URL of your server and then happens what?

Comment: it says css file not found, error 404

Comment: You are mixing gorilla/mux.Router and net/http.Handle willy-nilly. Don't do that. Use one or the other. And note that they match "catch-all" routes differently, so whichever you choose you should make sure the static path handler is setup accordingly.

Comment: this user has a similar record working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783541/how-can-i-find-css-files-using-golang-gorilla-mux

how to set the path to the static folder using only gorilla/mux.Router? I did not find a way to do this, instead I found information that gorilla/mux.Router and net/http.Handle can work together without conflicts

Comment: ok, it works if i use only net/http.Handle, but how do i make it work when i use gorilla/mux.Router?

Comment: @delpid go to gorilla/mux github.com project page and read the README, there's an example of how to setup a static file handler using `PathPrefix`. Link: https://github.com/gorilla/mux#static-files

Comment: @delpid and yes, it's easy to make them work together but there's no reason to. So don't do that. Use one or the other but not both, not in that way. That code in the answer you've linked ought not to pass the code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't mix `net/http.Handle` and `gorilla/mux.Router`

you can do it like this

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/index", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/html/test.html")
}
```

or like this

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))))
    r.HandleFunc("/index", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/html/test.html")
}
```